# Dropdown button won't work as expected using tailwind css

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

When clicking on the user profile which is supposed to show the dropdown menu, nothing is appearing.

```
`     <button type="button" class="flex mr-3 text-sm bg-gray-800 rounded-full md:mr-0 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-300 dark:focus:ring-gray-600" id="user-menu-button" aria-expanded="false" data-dropdown-toggle="user-dropdown" data-dropdown-placement="bottom">
        <span class="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
        <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full" src="/docs/images/people/profile-picture-3.jpg" alt="user photo">
      </button>
      <!-- Dropdown menu -->
      <div class="z-50 hidden my-4 text-base list-none bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-600" id="user-dropdown">
        <div class="px-4 py-3">
          <span class="block text-sm text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Bonnie Green</span>
          <span class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 truncate dark:text-gray-400">name@flowbite.com</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="py-2" aria-labelledby="user-menu-button">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-white">Dashboard</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-white">Settings</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-white">Earnings</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-white">Sign out</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>`
```

Using this nothing is appearing when clicking on the user menu
Resouce used: [`flowbite.com`](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/navbar/#user-menu-dropdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you [installed Flowbite](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/quickstart/)?

They most likely use javascript to remove the `hidden` class from the dropdown menu when the button is clicked. If you just copy the HTML+CSS it won't work.